# JavaScript - Document write call being skipped

Tags: javascript

Writing a JavaScript function to print 'Computing', perform whatever, then print the answer to the same area

```
function compute() {
    document.getElementById('solution').innerHTML = 'Computing'
    .
    .
    document.getElementById('solution').innerHTML = 'Answer: ' + x
}
```

My problem is that no matter how much time is elapsed, it never seems to actually print 'Computing' and only prints the Answer. What method should I use to ensure that the first document change is applied and not ignored?

Comment: It is already applied. You just overwrite it immediately afterward, so it has no visible result.

Comment: But even if it takes 5 or 10 seconds to get the the second write, it still doesnt perfom the first one.

Comment: What is the code in between? What takes 5 to 10 seconds?

Comment: If the operation that you say takes 5 or 10 seconds is asynchronous the program continues executing your instructions sequentially and you end up getting your result after the second write has occurred. Make sure to either check that your entire code is synchronous or that your second write is triggered by an event at the end of the operation.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you set the `innerHTML` to `Computing`, then immediately overwrite it. You can append the new text with `solution` in a new line like so:

```
function compute() {
    document.getElementById('solution').innerHTML = 'Computing';
    document.getElementById('solution').innerHTML += '<br>Answer: ' + x
}
```